# Why fo:footnote is missing

Tags: xsl-fo

I am trying to use `fo:footnote` but sometimes it's missing. How can I avoid this kind of situation?

First img - `fo:footnote` exists
Second img - there is only `fo:footnote`'s border and next page doesn't has fo:footnote.

[image]

-

[image]

Code. I have removed not necessary data. Version 1.0(I am not able to change version btw).

```
                    <fo:block>
                    <fo:footnote>
                        <fo:inline />
                        <fo:footnote-body>
                            <fo:block-container width="101.45%" margin-left="-5px" border-top="1px solid black">
                                <fo:block></fo:block>
                            </fo:block-container>
                            <fo:block keep-together.within-column="always">
                                <fo:block letter-spacing="-0.1px">
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:footnote-body>
                    </fo:footnote>
                </fo:block>
```

Comment: Which version of which formatter are you using?  Can you add some sample XSL-FO?  If you add or remove body text so that the footnote anchor is on a different page, does the footnote then appear? Can you use **focheck** (https://github.com/AntennaHouse/focheck) to check the structure of your XSL-FO?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. Code has been added. Gonna check that repo.

Comment: Probably not the cause of your problem, but the rule at the top of the footnote is usually done with an `fo:static-content` with `flow-name="xsl-footnote-separator"`. Search 'xsl-footnote-separator' in https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/. Also, there's multiple footnote examples in the XSL-FO samples at https://www.antennahouse.com/xsl-fo-samples. Lastly, pixels are seldom the best length unit to use. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#pixels

Comment: I have tried to use `for:static-content` but I have no idea why footer is not generated while I have only 1 or 2 pages but it present if I have 3 or more pages.
`<fo:region-after region-name="last-page-footer" />`
`<fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="last-page" />`
`<fo:static-content flow-name="last-page-footer">`

Comment: Which formatter are you using? Can you try a different formatter? Is your `fo:inline` empty in the real document? If your document has three or more pages, can you get footnotes on pages 1 and 2 of that document? Are you using a different `fo:simple-page-master` for the first two pages? Can you try putting your footnote in the FO file from one of the Antenna House samples to see what happens?

Comment: Your previous comment makes it look like you are putting your footnotes in an `fo:static-content`. Footnotes don't go into an `fo:static-content`. The `fo:footnote` is part of the `fo:flow`, and the formatter makes a sub-region within the `fo:region-body` area only on pages that have footnotes. See, e.g., https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#d0e14419